# How to count and get nested tree view list in c#

Tags: c#

This is link of image model of tree.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9kGF.jpg)

I'm trying to.many methods but I couldn't get data.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please add any code you have tried, and what your data structure looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to count items in a tree, you need to do some kind of tree traversal. There are lots of resources regarding those, one of which is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

```
Depth First Traversals:
(a) Inorder (Left, Root, Right) : 4 2 5 1 3
(b) Preorder (Root, Left, Right) : 1 2 4 5 3
(c) Postorder (Left, Right, Root) : 4 5 2 3 1
```

Depending on how you want to count, you need to implement the traversal method of choice. Based on the picture, i think you want `1. Preorder Traversal`. here is an example of an N-ary tree (a tree with several items per branch) https://leetcode.com/articles/introduction-to-n-ary-trees/

Comment: I have added image link in description. please check image. inside image designed tree view.

Comment: Like inside tree there 2 top member user1 and user2. user1 added  5 new members(user3,user4,user5,user6,user7) . same concept follows everyone. each one added five members. then now i want to get no. of member user1 tree. But user1 added only 5 member and  and there parentid added of user1, but child of user1 also added 5 members.